# Push Notification for square and wide tiles

Tags: javascript, windows-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am using [Azure Mobile Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj860484.aspx) for sending push notifications to my client app.  I send both square and tile notification using the push.wns object (first square and then wide).  Below is how the server-side code that sends push notifications looks like (this is basically called whenever a record is updated in my DB table):

```
function update(item, user, request) {
request.execute({
    success: function() {
        request.respond();
        sendNotifications();
    }
});

function sendNotifications() {
    var channelTable = tables.getTable('channel');

    channelTable.read({
        success: function(channels) {
            channels.forEach(function(channel) {
                push.wns.sendTileSquarePeekImageAndText02(channel.pushuri, 
                {image1src: '<imgPath>', 
                text1: 'New Game',
                text2: item.playername  }, 
                    { 
                     success: function(pushResponse) { console.log("Sent Square:", pushResponse); },
                     error: function(error) {
                                console.log("error sending push notification to ", channel.pushuri);
                                if (error.statusCode == 410) {
                                    console.log("Deleting ", channel);
                                    channelTable.del(channel.id);               
                                }
                            }  
                    });

                push.wns.sendTileWidePeekImage01(channel.pushuri, 
                {image1src: <imgPath>, 
                text1: 'New Game',
                text2: item.playername  }, 
                    { 
                     success: function(pushResponse) { console.log("Sent Square:", pushResponse); },
                     error: function(error) {
                                console.log("error sending push notification to ", channel.pushuri);
                                if (error.statusCode == 410) {
                                    console.log("Deleting ", channel);
                                    channelTable.del(channel.id);               
                                }
                            }  
                    });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

I notice that the wide notification is displayed correctly when my app tile is wide.  However, when I make the tile size of my app to square, the square notification is not displayed.  How can I correct this?

Comment: Almost impossible to answer without some code.

Comment: @DanielKelley added some code

Comment: It's not clear why this was tagged as C# when your code is not C#.

Comment: I've retagged the question as JavaScript and WinJS.

Comment: ah my bad.  My client app is C# although the entire cloud infrastructure that pushes notifications to this app is in Javascript

Comment: @JKor this code has nothing to do with WinJS.  All this Javascript code is on the server side.

Comment: I'll remove that tag then.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12603719/1656796

Comment: JFYI, this is being tracked here: https://github.com/tjanczuk/wns/issues/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's sample which you can use to send one update and update two kind of tiles at once.

```
push.wns.send(item.channel,
'<tile><visual>' +
'<binding template="TileSquarePeekImageAndText02">' + 
    '<image id="1" src="imageUri" />' + 
    '<text id="1">Template: TileSquarePeekImageAndText02</text>' + 
    '<text id="2">' + item.text + '</text>' + 
'</binding>' + 
'<binding template="TileWidePeekImage01">' + 
    '<image id="1" src="imageUri" />' + 
    '<text id="1">Template: TileWidePeekImage01</text>' + 
    '<text id="2">' + item.text + '</text>' + 
'</binding>' + 
'</visual></tile>',
"wns/toast", {
    success: function(pushResponse) {
        console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The tile notification with the wide content is replacing the tile notification containing the square content.  A single notification should be sent [containing both square and wide tile content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605685/1656796).

Comment: Would you happen to know how to construct that payload on the server-side using Javascript?

Comment: It appears that the sendTile* methods only send a single type of content (square or wide).  To construct a notification with both square and wide content, use the [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj860484.aspx#send) method and explicitly pass in the notification XML.

Comment: That's what I meant.  I am new to javascript, JSON, XML etc.  Do you know how to construct that piece of xml payload?